# Delete Sidekiq jobs with a particular argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

Say that at some point I enqueue a job that looks like this:

```
HardWorker.perform(command_id, user_id)
```

Is there any way I can remove all the jobs (from the Redis queue) which have a particular `command_id` associated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
command_id = 'command id to delete'

queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new('the_queue_name')

queue.each do |job|
  if job.klass == 'HardWorker' && job.args.first == command_id
    job.delete
  end
end
```